# How to return the callback in a variable in node.js with npm synchronize

Tags: node.js, synchronized

I'm using nodejs and I want to avoid multiple nested callbacks. How can I use synchonize to do that ?
More precisely how can I return the pubkeysObj from the callback of the request in a variable and use it in the rest of the script ?

```
var sync = require('synchronize');
var fiber = sync.fiber;
var await = sync.await;
var defer = sync.defer;

try {
    fiber(function() {
        console.log('before findKeyPair');
        var pubkeysObj2 = await( findKeyPair( defer() ) );
        console.log('after findKeyPair pubkeysObj2: ' + pubkeysObj2);

        console.log('before makeKeyPairs');
        var pubkeyArray2 = await( makeKeyPairs( pubkeysObj2, defer() ) );
        console.log('after makeKeyPairs pubkeyArray2: ' + pubkeyArray2);
    });
} catch(err) {
    console.log('err: ' + err);
}

function findKeyPair(){
   Keypair.find({}, {pubkey: 1, _id: 0}, function(err, pubkeysObj) { //mongoose db
      if (err) res.redirect('/');
      console.log('inside findKeyPair pubkeysObj: ' + pubkeysObj);
      return pubkeysObj;   // ?????????
   });
}

function makeKeyPairs(pubkeysObj3){
   console.log('inside makeKeyPairs: pubkeysObj3:' + pubkeysObj3);
   var pubkeyArray = [];
   pubkeyArray = Object.keys(pubkeysObj3).map(function(_) { return pubkeysObj3[_].pubkey; })
   return pubkeyArray;  // ????
}
```

The output is:

```
before findKeyPair
inside findKeyPair pubkeysObj: { pubkey: 'n2eTmd37KTGhRZNJsf9tfVdCG1YejciETu' },{ pubkey: 'n2cBvz74bMGUf35gAdnSksbBnW1m4HfCmg' }
```

Comment: Would you be open to using wait.for? It provides a nice fiber wrapper that lets you return data from an asynchronous call.

Answer (score 1):

> Would you be open to using wait.for?

I rewrote my code using "wait.for" and now I can receive the object KeypairObj from the database and pass it to the next function makeKeyPairs.
Inside this function I can print my array (pubkeyArray) but
I can't get the returned value (pubkeyArray2) and the last line of the function findKeyPair is not executed.

here is the new code:

```
var wait = require('wait.for');
var Keypair = require('./app/models/Keypair');

try {
   // launch a new fiber
   wait.launchFiber(findKeyPair, Keypair);
}
catch(err) {
   console.log('err' + err);
}

function findKeyPair(Keypair){
   var KeypairObj = wait.forMethod(Keypair,'find', {}, {pubkey: 1, _id: 0});
   console.log('1: ' + KeypairObj.toString());
   var pubkeyArray2 = wait.for(makeKeyPairs, KeypairObj);
   console.log('3: pubkeyArray2: ' + pubkeyArray2);  // not executed !!!
}

function makeKeyPairs(pubkeysObj3){
   pubkeyArray = Object.keys(pubkeysObj3).map(function(_) { return pubkeysObj3[_].pubkey; });
   console.log('2: pubkeyArray: ' + pubkeyArray);
}
```

and the output:

```
1: { pubkey: 'n2eTmd37KTGhRZNJsf9tfVdCG1YejciETu' },{ pubkey: 'n2cBvz74bMGUf35gAdnSksbBnW1m4HfCmg' }
2: pubkeyArray: n2eTmd37KTGhRZNJsf9tfVdCG1YejciETu,n2cBvz74bMGUf35gAdnSksbBnW1m4HfCmg
```

Comment: Update: I found the problem: the function makeKeyPairs does not return a value in a callback, so there is no need for a wait.for. The correct line is
    `var pubkeyArray2 = Object.keys(KeypairObj).map(function(_) { return KeypairObj[_].pubkey; });`